# Identity 2.1 email service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, email, sendgrid

I am developing a MVC 5 internet application, and am wishing to send an email using the `SendGrid` service when my application is deployed to `Azure`.

I have found some resource links, yet each different code implementation that I use, sends the email very slowly. I have chosen to use the code from this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762427/ASP-NET-Identity-Setting-Up-Account-Validation-and

Here is my code:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Credentials:
        var sendGridUserName = "myusername";
        var sentFrom = "test@email.com";
        var sendGridPassword = "mypassword";

        // Configure the client:
        var client =
            new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", Convert.ToInt32(587));

        client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        // Creatte the credentials:
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
            new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sendGridUserName, sendGridPassword);

        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        // Create the message:
        var mail =
            new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(sentFrom, message.Destination);

        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;

        // Send:
        return client.SendMailAsync(mail);
    }
}
```

The email takes many minutes to send. Why is this? How fast should the email be sent on average, and do I need to optimize my code in any way? Also, rather than using `SendGrid`, is there a better resource to use that I should use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask if you encountered the "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" error, and how you mitigated it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere on Sendgrid documentation (can't find it now unfortunately) I have seen recommendation that if you use their REST API endpoints instead of SMPT, the emails will arrive quicker. And Sendgrid provides C# library to use their API. Give it a go.

Comment: Hmm, the REST API will be faster, but not minutes faster. There are other reasons to use the REST API though.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible SendGrid is deferring or delaying your sends. Is there any defer or delay activity in your SendGrid dashboard?

You can also connect to the [SendGrid Webhook Events](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) to see exactly what's going on with your emails.